# Inverting a hash value (that's an array) into new individual keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following:

```
lumpy_hash = { 1 => ["A", "B"] }
```

then if I invoke `Hash#invert` on this hash, I'd like to get:

```
lumpy_hash = {"A" => 1, "B" => 1}
```

I don't get that from using `Hash#invert`. Any ideas on doing this? I'm not sure if I should try `Hash#map` or `Hash#invert`.

Comment: Thanks Cary - I'll edit the question. `"B"` should have the value `1`. The desired results of lumpy_hash (from your example) would be: {"A" => 12, "B" => 12, "D" => 12 }

Comment: You know that `invert` is already defined. And you want it to behave differently. Does that mean that you want to override the method?

Comment: @sawa - No intention of overwriting the method. Just trying to show my intention of inverting the Hash with the goal of trying to get the desired output as described. Thanks for getting clarification though, I can see how it may not have been totally clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one:

```
Hash[lumpy_hash.map { |k,v| v.product([k]) }.first]
 #=> {"A"=>1, "B"=>1}
```

I don't think the method [Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert) is useful here.

The steps:

```
enum = lumpy_hash.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: {1=>["A", "B"]}:map> 
k,v = enum.next
  #=> [1, ["A", "B"]] 
k #=> 1 
v #=> ["A", "B"] 
a = v.product([k])
  #=> ["A", "B"].product([1])
  #=> [["A", 1], ["B", 1]] 
Hash[a]
  #=> {"A"=>1, "B"=>1}
```

Here's another way that makes use of a hash's [default value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new). This one is rather interesting:

```
key,value = lumpy_hash.to_a.first
  #=> [1, ["A","B"]]
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=key }.tap { |h| h.values_at(*value) }
  #=> {"A"=>1,"B"=>1}
```

[Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) passes an empty hash to its block, assigning it to the block variable `h`. The block returns `h` after adding three key-value pairs, each having a value equal to the hash's default value. It adds the pairs merely by computing the values of keys the hash doesn't have!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, more pedestrian, method:

```
lumpy_hash.flat_map{|k,vs| vs.map{|v| {v => k}}}.reduce(&:merge)
 => {"A"=>1, "B"=>1}
```

Comment: Pedestrian? I think not. For one, I never tire of `reduce(&:merge)`.